# Can't get SWT Display on Mac OS X

Tags: swt, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I'm running Mac OS X Snow Leopard and wan't to access the Display from the activator in an OSGi bundle.

Below is the start method for my activator:

```
@Override
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    service.execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Display display = Display.getDefault();
            Shell shell = new Shell(display);
            Text helloText = new Text(shell, SWT.CENTER);
            helloText.setText("Hello SWT!");
            helloText.pack();
            shell.pack();
            shell.open();
            while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                    display.sleep();
            }
            display.dispose();
        }
    });
}
```

Calling this code in a Windows environment works fine, but deploying on Mac OS X I get the following output:

```
2009-10-14 17:17:54.050 java[2010:10003] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x101620d20 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2009-10-14 17:17:54.081 java[2010:10003] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100119240 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2009-10-14 17:17:54.084 java[2010:10003] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1001024b0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2009-10-14 17:17:54.086 java[2010:10003] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x7fff701d7f70 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2009-10-14 17:17:54.087 java[2010:10003] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100113330 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2009-10-14 17:17:54.092 java[2010:10003] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x101624540 of class NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
.
.
.
```

I've used the -XstartOnFirstThread VM argument without any luck. I'm on 64-bit Cocoa but I've also tried 32-bit Cocoa.

When trying on Carbon I get the following error:

```
Invalid memory access of location 00000020 eip=9012337c
```

When debugging into the Display class I can see that the Displays[] array only contains null references.

Comment: It works in Windows?  Really?  I'll have to try that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that we successfully run SWT **Carbon** on Mac OS X in its own event loop kicked off by a bundle activation, so it's definitely possible! This is using -XstartOnFirstThread when launching the VM.

**But**, with Cocoa SWT (64-bit), I see the same error :(

It seems that, although the way we ran Carbon SWT worked, it was probably not kosher: we were driving the event loop through another thread, not the main one as you're supposed to. Under Cocoa SWT, this doesn't work any more, and it was probably dodgy practice anyway.

I can fix the thread pool errors with the following hack before creating the Display (adapted from the Cocoa SWT Device constructor):

```
  NSAutoreleasePool pool = (NSAutoreleasePool) new NSAutoreleasePool().alloc().init();
  NSThread nsthread = NSThread.currentThread();
  NSMutableDictionary dictionary = nsthread.threadDictionary();
  NSString key = NSString.stringWith("SWT_NSAutoreleasePool");
  id obj = dictionary.objectForKey(key);
  if (obj == null) {
          NSNumber nsnumber = NSNumber.numberWithInteger(pool.id);
          dictionary.setObject(nsnumber, key);
  } else {
          pool.release();
  }
```

However, the event loop that follows hangs (i.e. the display.readAndDispatch ()/display.sleep () dance). I suspect it's just not reading UI events due not being the main thread.

I'm not sure if there's a kosher way to fix this. In my case, we control the main JVM thread that launches OSGi, so I'm toying with the idea of adding a hook in there that can run the SWT event loop after OSGi launch.

Comment: Is it possible to get hold of some simple code to get that up and running? And a working start configuration?

Comment: You've understood my question correctly. The last comment you're saying that you're looking to add a hook to run the SWT event loop. I believe that's supported by the Display class, once you've created the first instance of it in the main thread, the static methods will work as expected. At least if you believe the docs. From my understanding you will then be able to call Display.asyncExec(..) to execute code in the SWT event thread...that's how you do it in Eclipse at least.

Comment: Creating the Display instance in the main thread is the tricky part! We use a generic "bootstrap" class that launches the OSGi framework, and it has no idea about SWT or even access to the classes since they're actually loaded later by the SWT bundle.

My idea is to add some sort of generic hook to the bootstrap code, which the SWT bundle will use to get its loop executed by the main thread. The trick is to do this cleanly...

Comment: That was my initial idea too. Then I was wondering if this wasn't provided already by OSGi in some way...

Comment: That would be nice, but I strongly suspect OSGi won't be helpful. AFAIK OSGi spits off a bunch of threads to launch the bundles, and doesn't particularly know or care about the main thread. But I could be wrong: looking at the spec might be a good idea at this point.

If I get something working that might be generalisable, I'll post it here.

Comment: Just to expand: I have now successfully gotten an SWT OSGi bundle to run by allowing it to inject its event loop into the main thread (the one that kicks off OSGi) in combination with the -XstartOnFirstThread.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem that as soon as "display.sleep()" was called the Window freezed the application. If somebody else hace the same problem, the solution that worked for me was to add:
-XstartOnFirstThread
to the VM at the moment of the execution.

I was trying to make Areca Backup software work on my Mac, and know its working :)

My system is: MacOsX Snow Leopard 10.6.2

Bye,
Daniel W.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and resolved it by adding both `-d32` and `-XstartOnFirstThread`

Answer (score 0):

This code looks very strange... is this supposed to be an Eclipse plugin?  What are you trying to do?  I'll guess that you are trying to create an RCP plugin with a User Interface.  If so, here's the answer: Don't do that.  Your OSGi Activator is not be responsible for creating the SWT display event loop.

Create an application extension in your plugin.xml to declaratively create the SWT bootstrap.  It will look something like this:

```
   <extension
         id="application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application>
         <run
               class="com.yourcompany.foo.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
```

Then create the Application class (call it whatever you want) to look something like this:

```
public class Application implements IApplication {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication#start(org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext)
     */
    public Object start(IApplicationContext context) {
        Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
        try {
            int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor());
            if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART) {
                return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;
            }
            return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
        } finally {
            display.dispose();
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication#stop()
     */
    public void stop() {
        final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
        if (workbench == null)
            return;
        final Display display = workbench.getDisplay();
        display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (!display.isDisposed())
                    workbench.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Obviously make sure you have the SWT plugins (org.eclipse.ui) available in your Manifest as well as the runtime.

I hope that helps.

Comment: No I'm not trying to create an Eclipse plugin. I'm trying to use SWT in an OSGi environment without Eclipse RCP. I know that the Workbench in RCP is responsible for creating the Display and that it is performed in the main thread before any plugins are activated. AFAIK it should be possible to create the Display in any thread, as long as it is used as the UI thread after that. 

From the doc:
"In SWT, the thread which creates a Display  instance is distinguished as the user-interface thread  for that display."

Comment: However, I've learnt that Mac OS X requires that thread to be thread 0. That might explain why it works on windows but not on Mac. I don't know how to solve that though...

Comment: You want SWT without RCP but you want OSGi - seems strange.  RCP is basically SWT and OSGi with a few other plugins that you don't have to use if you don't want them.

Comment: RCP is much more than OSGi + SWT.

Comment: I would say more, not much more.  I've been developing on that platform for 5 years so I'm quite familiar.