# Executing Eclipse plugin (jdt/ast) outside eclipse IDE environment

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

Can I execute [Eclipse Java development tools](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/) as a standalone process? I need to get Java program's [AST](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html) structure using Eclipse JDT from another program, and to do that, I need to execute eclipse plugin as a stand-alone process behind the scene.

Is that possible? If so, how one can do that?

Comment: It's probably possible, but it seems like it would be easier to use Eclipse to look at the Java program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse/jdt and eclipse/ast is nothing more than a jar file, so one can use them to build standalone java application.

### Example

I googled to find [ASTExplorer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ast/) as an example to make eclipse/ast plugin as a standalone java project.

The program was targeted for pretty old eclipse (3.0.2), I downloaded the [3.0.2](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.0.2-200503110845/) for Mac OS X this site - http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.0.2-200503110845/

1. You need to setup ECLIPSE_HOME classpath variables in Preference -> Java -> Classpath variables [image]
2. The .classpath has those classpath variables already, you can refer to this post - [.classpath contents update in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570286/classpath-contents-update-in-eclipse). As you can see it refers eclipse/jdt(art) jar files. I'm pretty sure one can change the reference to the newest version of jdt/ast without downloading the 3.0.2 version.
3. As I use Mac, I need to replace the swt for PC with swt for Mac. I could do that in BuildPath/Configure Build path [image]
   [image]

   1. First remove the PC swt reference.
   2. Then add the correct Mac swt reference.

### Compile the example with the eclipse indigo/on mac

When the setup is correct, eclipse starts building the project. You can use Project -> Build Project menu. Then, you can check the application works fine in eclipse. 
[image]

### Generate the executable jar

1. Export to executable jar file. 
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
2. You'll get some warnings, but you'll have a jar file.

### Execute the generated jar

Just executing `java -jar ast.jar` doesn't work on Mac, I got a hint from this post. 
[Running SWT based, cross-platform jar properly on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976342/running-swt-based-cross-platform-jar-properly-on-a-mac)

In short, you need to run `java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar ast.jar`

Answer (score 1):

Does it *have* to be Eclipses's AST?  Or is any AST generation o.k.?  If it doesn't have to be eclipse, I'd suggest Habelitz open source Java AST Compiler.  http://www.habelitz.com/  I'm using it myself for some projects....

Well, of course you can launch eclipse just like any other process : [How to create a process in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006035/how-to-create-a-process-in-java)

And then the problem becomes relaying the information back to the original process, which gets kind of messy.   My suggested approach in this case would probably be to create a plugin in eclipse and have that plugin do whatever it is you think you need the AST for.  You can work out messages with command line options to eclipse, or a shared file or something.