# When run a runnable jar file - it is not working

Tags: java, swt, desktop-application

I've created a desktop app using Java AWT. I can run the app successfully from the eclipse, but when I exported the runnable jar file and try to run it, it gave me an error and not working.
Here is the error:

```
***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions. Use vmarg -XstartOnFirstThread
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4723)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1437)
    at MainWindow.open(MainWindow.java:74)
    at MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
```

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Have you tried running it with the argument that the error message is telling you to use? `java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar YourJarFile.jar` or something like that?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. 
I tested it with the command, and it works. Now, how can I make it run automatically, so the user can double click and run it?

Comment: I guess one easy way is that you could provide a script that runs that command and instruct the user to run the script, not the jar.

Comment: I am getting this error in windows, while in mac it works prefectly.
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
        no swt-cocoa-4934r6 in java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin, C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin, C:\WINDOWS\system32, C:\WINDOWS, C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath, C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath, C:\Python38\Scripts\,

Comment: The intial question is potentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3976342; maybe also have a look at https://www.eclipse.org/swt/macosx/

Comment: None of the suggested links fixes the problem. My case is that I could run the jar file on a mac using the command: 
java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar YourJarFile.jar
While in windows, I couldn't get it run. 
When I applied the same command, it gave me: 
Unrecognized option: -XstartOnFirstThread
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
If I run it with the option "XstartOnFirstThread" it will not work.

Comment: If it's AWT as tagged and mentioned in the question, why is the stack trace referring to SWT?